# Django check form field attribute in template

Tags: django

I need to check if a form field is disabled in the template. The field is disabled depending on some other factors but I've simplified it below.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['quantity'].disabled = True
```

Then in the template I'd like to do something like this:

```
{% if form.quantity.disabled is True %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution through accessing [`field.field.disabled`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields)